# Who killed this Forsaken in The Fires of Heaven?

Tags: robert-jordan, wheel-of-time

> Asmodean pulled open a small door, intending to find his way to the
>   pantry. There should be some decent wine. One step, and he stopped,
>   the blood draining from his face. "You? No!" The word still hung in
>   the air when death took him.

Who killed Asmodean?

I am pretty sure it was one of the Forsaken, but which one? Demandred or Graendal or someone else?

Comment: Note that this topic is also covered on [scifi / fantasy stackexchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24315/)

Comment: Sooooooo Mr. Rand finally learned how to be in two places at once ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asmodean's killer is revealed in *Towers of Midnight.*  The glossary entry for Graendal states:

> "A ruthless killer, she was responsible for the deaths of Aran'gar and Asmodean and for the destruction of Mesaana."

And in the book, Shaidar Haran says this:

> "Three Chosen, destroyed by your actions."

---

Before that, there was a lot of speculation about who killed Asmodean.  The pinnacle of that was [this Sherlock Holmes fanfiction](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4975913/1/Sherlock-Holmes-Examines-the-Death-of-Asmodean) which pretty much explains all the reasoning used before it was revealed.

Comment: "The pinnacle of this was this Sherlock Holmes fanfiction" wait wot